# Checking if a new line exist using regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am writing a javascript to add {y} at the start and {/y) at the end to non english characters. I also need it to leave empty lines as it is. But in the current scenario, it is adding {y}{/y) to empty lines/new lines.

```js
var lyrics = document.getElementById('userInput');

function printSong() {
  var input = lyrics.value;
  var lines = input.split('\n');
  var generatedText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].match(/[A-z]|[0-9]{2}/) != null | lines[i].match(/\s/) != null) {
      generatedText = generatedText + lines[i] + '\n';
    } else {
      generatedText = generatedText + "{y}" + lines[i] + "{/y}" + '\n';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('output').value = generatedText;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <textarea id="userInput" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Enter song lyrics here">testing

அஇஉ்உ்உ</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="printSong()">Generate tags</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <textarea disabled id="output" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Generated Song"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can put your *HTML/CSS/JS* code and make them executable snippet.

Comment: Two things to notice: you are using a unary `|` inside an `if` and `[A-z]` matches more than just ASCII letters.

Comment: Do you want to find non english chars or lines that has non english characters?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've added some sample data in it.

Comment: @ReadyFreddy I want to find lines that have non english characters

Comment: @MichelleAshwini: Your current check only adds {y}{/y} around lines that have **only** characters not matching your expression. So for instance, if the line is `testingஇtesting`, you won't put markers around that, because the `t` in `testing` satisfies your regular expression. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What I am trying to achieve is when a song is entered; both the original language and then the romanised english below that line. {y}{/y} are to be added to the original language (NOT english). If it is a full english song, it should not add the {y}{/y}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding adding your markers to blank lines is simply a matter of adding

```
!lines[i].trim() ||
```

...to the beginning of your `if`. That takes the line, strips any leading and trailing whitespace from it, and sees if the result is empty. (`""` is a *falsy* value, so `!""` is `true`.) If it is blank, it skips the regex check (because `||` short-circuits if the left-hand operand is truthy) and we go into the `if` block (so we don't add markers to blank lines).

But as [Wiktor pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828515/checking-if-a-new-line-exist-using-regex/42828662#comment72767202_42828515):

- For the logical OR operation, it's `||`, not `|`
- `[A-z]` matches all characters between upper case A and lower case z. There are many characters after Z and before a that will also be matched.

Also: `[A-z]|[0-9]{2}` means "a single character A through z or two digits." If that's what you really meant, fine, but if you meant "two characters which are either A through z or 0 through 9" you'd combine them into a single character class. I **haven't** done that below, on the theory you may want the condition the way it is.

And finally: If all you want to do is check if a string matches an expression, you don't want `match`; instead, use `test` on the expression. E.g.

```
if (string.match(expression) != null)
```

becomes

```
if (expression.test())
```

That lets the regular expression engine stop as soon as it knows the result and not bother to build the result array.

With those changes:

```js
var lyrics = document.getElementById('userInput');

function printSong() {
  var input = lyrics.value;
  var lines = input.split('\n');
  var generatedText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (!lines[i].trim() || /[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]{2}/.test(lines[i]) || lines[i].match(/\s/) != null) {
      generatedText = generatedText + lines[i] + '\n';
    } else {
      generatedText = generatedText + "{y}" + lines[i] + "{/y}" + '\n';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('output').value = generatedText;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <textarea id="userInput" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Enter song lyrics here">testing

அஇஉ்உ்உ</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align: center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="printSong()">Generate tags</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <textarea disabled id="output" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Generated Song"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly how I want it to work. In `!lines[i].trim() || lines[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]{2}/) != null || lines[i].match(/\s/) != null)`, what is `!lines[i].trim()` doing?

Comment: @MichelleAshwini: I should have explained. It checks to see if `lines[i]` is blank (other than whitespace) and if so takes us into the `if` block. `lines[i]` is, of course, the line. `.trim()` strips any whitespace from the beginning and end. `!` coerces the resulting string to boolean and negates it. Since `""` coerces to `false`, `!""` is `true`. So blank lines don't get markers.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Also, i did not know i could use test instead. I ended up using test. Using the `!lines[i].trim() || lines[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]{2}/) != null || lines[i].match(/\s/) != null)`, did not create tags for cases where i had `1. இஉஊஉ` but added tags when it was  `1.இஉஊஉ`. Instead, I used this `lines[i].match(/[A-z]|[0-9]{2}/) != null || ! /\S/.test(lines[i])`. This added the tags for both  `1. இஉஊஉ` and `1.இஉஊஉ`.